# Invalid stream header: 2C6D0005 - StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, servlets, browser

I downloaded a serialized Java object from my servlet application. When I try to open it in Java code I get:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 2C6D0005

I searched internet and could not find any reference to code **2C6D0005**.

What could cause this?

Note that I have used this servlet application to download many other serialized objects and have not seen this problem before.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error code. It's the first 4 bytes of the file you think is serialized data, but isn't.

The bytes should be `AC ED 00 05` where the first two bytes are "magic" and `00 05` is version.

See [Java Serialization Algorithm Revealed](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html) for the file format as well as other information, and [The Specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/pdf/serial-spec.pdf) if something is still unclear.

Edit:

Fine, I'll spare you the suspense since I have to leave work. Somewhere, someone is not reading bytes properly. If you clear the high bit of `AC` and `ED`, you get..... `2C` and `6D`. You should talk with the person who wrote the relevant code and then fix it.

Comment: 2C6D0005 is the first 4 bytes in my downloaded serialized file? and is should always be ACED0005?

Comment: Why are you asking me? I don't have the file.

Comment: Opened my file in hex editor. The fiest 4 bytes are `AC ED 20 05`. What could have caused this?

Comment: Well, if the file is correct on the filesystem but corrupted in the program, it's usually the programmer's fault. That or solar flares.

Comment: My first 4 bytes are `AC ED 20 05`. Does this mean corruption? Since it is supposed to be `AC ED 00 05`.  And why the error says 'invalid stream header: 2C6D0005'?

Comment: So you've got three versions of the file? The plot thickens. *In any case*. Somewhere before Java's serialization mechanism gets a hold of your bytes, they become corrupted. Maybe even several times. The solution is somewhere in your code.